# Json parsing issue(values auto changed float)

Tags: java, android, json

Hi i have mention my json format below

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "MinValue": 2,
    "MaxValue": 29
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "MinValue": 0.5,
    "MaxValue": 5.6
}]
```

While i am parsing the MinValue & MaxValue its return like 2.0,29.0(float)
Kindly help me to get exact value.

My parsing code

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

if (jsonArray != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject profileObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String minValue = profileObject.getString(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MINVALUE);
            String maxValue = profileObject.getString(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MAXVALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 0.2 or 2.0? Big difference

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes it is, I guess the number that it's not different is 29 to 29.0

Comment: So which one is it? 0.2 or 2.0?

Comment: `29.0` is an exact value for `29`, and it is likely a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: sorry i am getting (2.0,29.0)

Comment: Why are you extracting an int with getString()?

Comment: I need to parse exact value.

Comment: It's showing fine on mine, what about `profileObject.getInt("MinValue")`. This will ignore the value after decimal.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna losing the precision is obviously not a good idea

Comment: which version of org.json are you using?

Comment: @RameshThangaraj can you provide some feedback on the answers, downvote or upvote, let us know if it works etc. Right now you have 5 people putting in effort to help you and all score of 0

Answer (score 1):

Replace this with

```
String minValue = profileObject.getString(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MINVALUE);
String maxValue = profileObject.getString(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MAXVALUE);
```

this

```
double minValue = profileObject.getDouble(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MINVALUE, 0);
double maxValue = profileObject.getDouble(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MAXVALUE, 0);
```

as per json data min and max values are clearly Double not String.

Comment: 0.5 and 5.6 are most certainly not integers and retrieving them with getInt will lose the precision

Comment: sorry, my bad .. UPDATED

Answer (score 0):

You can get the double value from `JSON` then remove `.0` if needed

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat=new DecimalFormat("#.#");
double minValue = decimalFormat.format(profileObject.getDouble(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MINVALUE));
double maxValue = decimalFormat.format(profileObject.getDouble(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MAXVALUE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

if (jsonArray != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject profileObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Object minValue = profileObject.get(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MINVALUE);
            if (minValue instanceof Integer) {
                int min = (int) minValue;
            } else if (minValue instanceof Double) {
                double min = (double) minValue;
            }

            Object maxValue = profileObject.get(Constants.VALUE_BMCPROFILE_MAXVALUE);
            if (maxValue instanceof Integer) {
                int max = (int) maxValue;
            } else if (maxValue instanceof Double) {
                double max = (double) maxValue;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Then proceed with the int or double to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you are really getting trouble then the alternate solution is remove `.0` like this

```
   if(MinValue.endsWith(".0")){
         String myMinValue = MinValue.substring(0,MinValue.indexOf('.'))        
    }
```

Comment: This is avoiding the problem, the real solution would be to not store it in a string in the first place

Comment: May i know Why this issue happen?
Min and Max are the string value only

Comment: I have tested the same JSON you were providing above but the results were proper.

Comment: @RameshThangaraj It's an alternate solution, If Logic of Tim Castelijns didn't work then you can apply this. This will remove your `.0` suffix and gives proper integer.